# Input not fitting to CNN architecture

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torch

I implemented a CNN Model and the first part of it looks as follows:

```
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,padding=2),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(32), 
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2,stride=2,padding=1),
    nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,dilation=2,padding=2),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(64), nn.ReLU(),
    #...
```

I am trying to run the Model, but I keep getting this error
**Expected 2D (unbatched) or 3D (batched) input to conv1d, but got input of size: [4]**

When I reshape the input, using tensor reshape, I get this new error
**RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 6 elements not 32**

What does that mean? How can I fix this? Would that be related to the nn.BatchNorm1d?

Comment: Because of the questions formatting regulations I could not post the whole CNN

Comment: What is your input shape? `Conv2d` expects its input to be a 4D tensor in the shape of (B, C, H, W); otherwise, it will throw an error.

Comment: @TQCH The initial shape of input is torch.Size([4, 1, 1, 1, 1]) and I had to reshape it before entering the Conv1D, then my input x =  tensor([[0.1034, 0.1034], [0.1034, 0.1034]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ReshapeAliasBackward0>) causes the second error concerning the running_mean